# How can I fix raster_columns issue?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, postgis, heroku-postgres

I am trying to open server with Heroku credentials on PostgreSQL. But when I create extension postgis, the "ERROR:  relation "raster_columns" does not exist" error occurs. How can I fix it? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this installing postgres in other version.

```
  $ heroku create: heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --version=12
```

Answer (score 1):

Same error not able to fix.
I think there is issue with Heroku-Postgres since 30-04-2022.

The same code is working on local postgres server.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in this page: [Fixing a broken raster install](https://postgis.net/documentation/tips/tip-removing-raster-from-2-3/)

The trick is executing `CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;`